# Horizontal scrolling in editableDTUI and editableDT in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, editor, shinydashboard, modifier

i need to give flexibility to app user so that they can edit/modify a table . I am using the below codes
**UI code**:

```
tabItem(tabName = "manual_override",
            fluidRow(
              editableDTUI("table1")
```

**Server Codes:**

```
callModule(editableDT,"table1",data=reactive(bigtable),inputwidth=reactive(100))
```

but the problem is that **bigtable** has more than 15 columns to display and the horizontal scroll is not appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the same with library(DT) with 20 col.
If that solves your problem.

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

library(DT)

shinyUI(

  fluidPage(
   navbarPage("Big file upload + Horizental Scrolling",
            tabPanel("Data Import",
               fluidRow(
                 fileInput("file","Upload Your CSV",multiple = FALSE),
                 column(6,
                        div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll',  DT::dataTableOutput('csv_data')))
               )      
            )
   )
  )
)
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  csv_data_fun<-eventReactive(input$file,{
    df<-read.csv(input$file$datapath,
                 header =TRUE)
     return(df)
  })

  output$csv_data<-DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(csv_data_fun(),rownames = FALSE)%>%formatStyle(columns=colnames(csv_data_fun()),background = 'white',color='black')
  })
})
```

output Screen
[image]

Please check whether you want this

I have done with editDT, But this time with default mtcars dataset.
Added the code in UI part

```
div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll',editableDTUI("table1"))
```

New Code

```
library(shiny)
library(editData)

if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("mydata","Enter data name",value="mtcars"),
    column(6, 
           div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll',editableDTUI("table1")
               )
    )
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    df=callModule(editableDT,"table1",dataname=reactive(input$mydata),inputwidth=reactive(170))

    output$test=renderPrint({
      str(df())
    })

  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Please check this time if this solves your problem. You can tweak the things to change according to your requirements.
Please accept the answer if solves your issue.

Comment: your answer solves horizontal scrolling problem in `renderDataTable`

Comment: but my problem was to insert a scrolling in editableDT function using which user can add/modify a table. please see my UI and Server codes. the answer you have provided, does not give user to add/modify data in a table.

Comment: Thanks Subhasish                                                                                                That perfectly solves the problem